# Authenticate http request with certificate in REST service (NOT SSL/HTTPS)

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I've been searching all over Google for a solution and came out with nothing.
I have a REST service written in C# (using the WebServiceHost class), and I'm trying to achieve a simple task: A mutual authentication of both the server and the client using certificates, without encryption, SSL, or HTTPS, only through HTTP requests.

At the moment I can use a web browser to access `http://localhost:8000/MyService/Items/abc` and I get the response from my server, but I can't get the server to ask for authentication with certificates.
Best I could do is get the server to ask the user to identify themselves using AD username and password.

**EDIT:**
As (the other) Avi explained - it's not possible to have automatic certificate validation over HTTP as the protocol doesn't send or recieve certificates.
The only way this is possible is to write tour own "SSL-like" protocol that works over HTTP, which will double the amount of calls made back-and-forth and be inferior to the built-in SSL/TLS in every way possible.

Comment: Would this help [An easy way to use certificates for WCF security](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18601/An-easy-way-to-use-certificates-for-WCF-security)?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to do anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using .net client to invoke Rest service? If yes you can attach certificate to HttpWebRequest request. request.Certificates.Add(certficate). 
[check this link for configuring server for client certificate request](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

You need to enable ssl to select Require client certificate. Other option is accept certificate in which case it will allow the user to access resource and you need to provide other way of authenticating the user if client does not present certificate.
All these are valid only if accessing from sophisticated framework (like .net/Java). If you try to access from javascript I dont think you can attach client certificate. Only browser can send client certificate (Require client certificate setting) as part of normal http request.

whatever option I mentioned require ssl communication. With HTTP only you cannot have client certificate. 
Let say you are using .net client only
First request - send client cert pub key to server.  Server finds whether whether certficate exist in server by looking up the public key. Only valid users public key certificate are stored in server. If exist sends the token (let say 345) to client. 
Client signs the token and sends signed data(token  345 + encrypted token 876).
Server gets pub key for the token (which is stored in first request) and validates the signature (decrypts 876 and compares against token). If they match it is authenticated request other invalid.

This is just for information how to set up auth for per request basis. Why you should not use it 
- You will end up having 2 request for each call which is not good. 
- You need to check validity and whether cerificate is valid (that it is not revoked by CA) so basically you will end up like ssl communication (minus encrypting the request/response itself which require encrypted token)

In simple word you cannot have client certificate authentication mechanism without ssl

Comment: First of all thanks for the response.

1. At this early stage I'm calling my service from a browser, but later it will be called from .NET code.

2. So from what I understood its possible to write a custom authentication method, where I can write the certificate authentication logic?
Could you please direct me to an example of such custom authentication over HTTP? it sounds exactly what I need.

Comment: So basically, the only way is to write my own "SSL-like" protocol that works over HTTP, which will double the amount of calls made back-and-forth and be inferior to the built-in SSL/TLS in every way possible.
Thanks a lot!